# Altair 'Scatter Plot with Href' example no longer working?

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I found that a map I created with href in the tooltip was not working today.   After trying 3 browsers on my Mac and a re-boot, I switched to Linux and found the same thing.   
 
So, I checked the Altair example that it was based on here:

https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_href.html

And this also does not work for me.   The Tooltip dialogue appears normally but the html link is not active.
 
I did notice at first it worked when I tried on a Linux machine (in Chrome but not Firefox) but after clearing my cache in Chrome it also stopped working.   The Altair example also is not functional on a different Mac.  I’ve never had any problems with this before--- even worked on a iPad.
 
So, I’m curious what might explain this loss of critical functionality.     I realize this might not directly be an Altair issue but maybe related to Vega-lite or javascript, but I’m not knowledgeable about these at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Vega 5.12.1. If you render your chart with a different Vega version, it will work. See https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2641 for more information.

Comment: I can confirm it works as expected with Vega set to 5.12.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to choose a specific Vega version when saving as html (using altair-saver)?

Comment: Sure, use e.g. ``altair_saver.save(chart, 'filename.html', vega_version='5.12.2')``